# Create templates with multiple variable texts on top of an image in Swift

Tags: swift, templates, text, calayer, layer

Let's say;

There's an image loaded in imageview.

There's 3 data fetched from outside source (so this data is not fixed)

1. Image loaded in imageview
2. Data which is in text are arranged to create a 'template' or 'layer'.
3. This 'template' or 'layer' is placed on top of the loaded image.
4. All of the 'layers' (image & template) compressed/rasterize to create a single output image.

Please guide me how to do this? Is it somehow have to do with CALayer?

And after this, I want to create multiple 'templates' i.e. various arrangements of texts, so that the user can select which templates best.

Ideas?

I'm new with Swift & Objective-C. I used to code basic html, php, css stuff.

Comment: Are you trying to have some text displayed on top of your image view?

Comment: Yes. So there's more than one set of text. There's three data, so three set of texts which I want to create them as a layer. Then placed that one layer containing three set of texts, on top of an image. Then rasterize them all together as one exported image. Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay. So you want this layer, but not actually apply them to the image itself, right?

Comment: Yes and no. So there would be a few templates/layers (with different style of  arrangements of texts) where the user can choose from. Once chosen, then the chosen layer will be applied to the image.